# RunMdaInstall task not given value for required parameter 'MdaVsixDir" while trying to build a cordova project

Tags: cordova, tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I'm having an issue with Cordova (TACO) builds on TFS.  The Tools for Apache Cordova were installed on the TFS servers and it seems that they are being recognized, however, I'm getting the following below build output.

```
Build started 1/5/2016 11:00:40 AM.
 1>Project "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
 1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
     Building solution configuration "Debug|Android".
 1>Project "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject.sln" (1) is building "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.jsproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
 2>PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\tsc.exe COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY
   CompileTypeScript:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\tsc.exe 
 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(287,5): error MSB4044: The "RunMdaInstall" task was not given a value for the required parameter "MdaVsixDir". [D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.jsproj]
 2>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.jsproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
 1>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

   "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.jsproj" (default target) (2) ->
   (InstallMDA target) -> 
     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(287,5): error MSB4044: The "RunMdaInstall" task was not given a value for the required parameter "MdaVsixDir". [D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.jsproj]

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.26
```

The specific error is:

> error MSB4044: The "RunMdaInstall" task was not given a value for the required parameter "MdaVsixDir". [D:\Builds\22\Cordova\MyProject\src\Cordova\Mainline\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.jsproj

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1894979/cordova-update-3-totally-breaks-project-type) helps...

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  We checked this location on the build servers under the account that runs the build and that particular folder they say to delete doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was on an older version of cordova tools that required me to set the environment variables as denoted here - http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfs2013/